# How to properly access "dynamic" added properties on Objects on Angular strict mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG (Angular) and under the strict mode, one of its documentation case is this:

```
if (window['Prism']) {
...any code
}
```

The VSCode shows me this: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

But I don't know how to bypass this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd cast window to unknown first like this

```
(window as unknown).Prism
```

https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 2):

You can declare it to tell the TypeScript compiler the property `Prism` is defined somewhere else:

```js
declare interface Window { // NOTE: Capital "W"
    Prism: any;
};
```

If you known the actual type of `window.Prism` you can specify it instead of `any`.